# scale_color_gradient does not adhere to breaks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to align the color scales of multiple graphs, but I can't seem to set fixed limits for color in ggplot.  For example, in the Reprex below, the complete spectrum from white to aqua is used for points with values ranging from 2 to 4, even though I set the breaks to (0,10).  I would expect that all of the points on this graph would be a "mid-range" blue, but there are white and aqua points showing.

How can I get a fixed color scale?

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point(size = 6) +
  scale_color_gradient(low = "white", high = "#00b7f1", breaks =  c(0,10))
```

Comment: Are you not just looking for the `limits = ` argument instead of the `breaks = `?

Comment: Are you looking for scale_color_binned()
scale_color_discrete()
scale_color_manual()
scale_color_steps()

Comment: Indeed I was.  Thank you @teunbrand!